# Force a Windows location change when in a masked domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, hyperlink, forwarding

Our client has 2 websites that have identical content, so we got rid of one, and used a masked forward on one of the domains so it still feels like both sites are there.

We then used a sweet try catch with JavaScript to check if the site is being accessed through the masked frame to make minor aesthetic changes in jQuery.

```
try
{
if ( top.document.domain != self.document.domain );
}
catch(e)
{
// jQuery to change a few colors and positions.
}
```

All of this works fantastically, except for **if you want to go from the masked version of the site to the actual domain using the header link, it fails, and forces you to stay on the masked version**, no matter which method we use for changing the Windows location.

I know we could avoid this by not using masked forwarding, and customizing the iframe so that the header link is outside of the iframe. But we'd rather not as we would have to get involved with the IT department and they are reluctant to make changes. We obviously will do this if there is no solution. Here's to hoping there is one!

Link to the real working sites:

The Masked Domain: http://mdpa.com/

The Actual Domain: http://worthe.com/

Comment: Can you post an example of this in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by changing the target of the header link.

```
target="_top"
```

Without the target attribute, it defaults to the iframe. Since you're using the onclick attribute (which doesn't seem necessary), you need to change it as well.

```
window.top.location='something'
```

Change your header link code in the actual domain from this:

```
<a href="http://worthe.com" onclick="window.location='http://worthe.com'; return false;" class="logo" id="logo-worthe">Worthe Real Estate Group</a>
<a href="http://mdpa.com" onclick="window.location='http://mdpa.com'; return false;" class="logo" id="logo-mdpa">M. David Paul and Associates</a>
<a href="http://worthe.com" onclick="window.location='http://worthe.com'; return false;" class="logo" id="logo-krismar">Krismar Construction</a>
```

to this:

```
<a href="http://worthe.com" onclick="window.top.location='http://worthe.com'; return false;" class="logo" id="logo-worthe" target="_top">Worthe Real Estate Group</a>
<a href="http://mdpa.com" onclick="window.top.location='http://mdpa.com'; return false;" class="logo" id="logo-mdpa" target="_top">M. David Paul and Associates</a>
<a href="http://worthe.com" onclick="window.top.location='http://worthe.com'; return false;" class="logo" id="logo-krismar" target="_top">Krismar Construction</a>
```